# Can we use Application Client ID + Client Secret instead of Tokens

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to use the combination of Application's Client ID + Client Secret for API Authentication instead of an OAuth Token.

Is it possible to do this with API Manager 4.x?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can write a custom handler to achieve this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the recommended way of getting an access token.  You have to use the client id and secret, then generate and access token using those.

This is a general practice and all the API Manager versions do support this capability.

**Update**:
You cannot just use client id and secret for authentication. The API Gateway is unable to authenticate the request with those credentials. Instead of client id and secret you can use an API key which has  an infinite expiry time.

Comment: I think you did not read my question properly. What I need is to avoid the generating of OAuth token and just use Client ID + Client Secret combination to authenticate APIs. 

Appreciate your response.